# How to call a renamed symbol in an external object file?

Tags: c++, linker, fuzzing, objcopy, libfuzzer

I am trying to fuzz a particular piece of code using LLVM libFuzzer that only exposes its `main()` function externally.  I have access to the source of the target code, but cannot change it.

If I try to directly include the object file, it conflicts with the `main` definition provided by `-fsanitize=fuzzer`.  I thought I might be able to solve this by renaming the `main` symbol in the object file:

```
objcopy --redefine-sym main=stub_main main.stub main.o
```

Then in my harness code, I should just declare:

```
extern int stub_main(int argc, char **argv)
```

And call `stub_main()` instead of `main()`, while including `main.stub` on the link line.  However, this did not seem to work, and the linker cannot find the reference to `stub_main(int, char**)`.

How can I call this `main` function from another piece of code that also provides its own `main()`?

Comment: Is your harness C++, by chance? Then you forgot to declare the stub as `extern "C"`

Comment: @Botje - that was it, thank you!  I am not sure why that is needed, since the target code is also C++, but it worked!  If you post this as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not accounting for C++'s [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling). The symbol for `stub_main` is likely a string containing main as well as some obfuscated info about arguments, type of function, and return type. In my platform it's **__Z9stub_mainiPPc**. The symbol for `main` would likely just be **main** or **main_**.

You can try looking how `main` and `stub_main` definitions mangle in your platform with `objdump -d *.o`, and then you can replace these strings with `objcopy --redefine-sym`.

Alternatively, as matoro said, you can declare the function as `extern "C"` so that no name mangling takes place.